# passing vars to pages in wordpress 6 and search them

Tags: links, query-variable, search-engines

I've got a number of challenges I'm trying to work through in WordPress 6.

I have 100s of items in a separate database I want to display on one page in WordPress. For example, I have a list of birds and some details about each one. What I'd like to do is create a link to a specific bird and show the details for the one bird on a page.

Right now, I have a template page (page-bird.php) that has a query to pull in the data based on a unique ID. What I need is a way to link to the page with that unique ID. Something like bird?b=4 so the query can use that 4.

I've tried using the technique mentioned on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4586835/how-to-pass-extra-variables-in-url-with-wordpress) (and similar), but WP 6 won't even let me enter PHP on the page editor.

What's the best practice for this?

The next thing I need to deal with is a way to search this content. I realize the built-in search engine is pretty weak so is there a plugin that will index dynamic content? I'd prefer a freebie or single-purchase version. No monthly costs.

Thank you!

Comment: WordPress has never allowed PHP in the editor. That's not what those older solutions are expecting you to do. When adding custom functionality to WordPress with code your code belongs in a plugin or your theme's functions.php file. I suggest checking the Developer Resources if you're new to WordPress: https://developer.wordpress.org

Comment: I haven't used WordPress since v3 or 4 and am just having another look at it. I'll check the resources for this, but what about the search? Is any search engine capable of searching this kind of content?

Comment: Also, could you be a little more specific about the functions.php file? I can write my own function, but don't know what function to write to achieve this.

Comment: Could anyone nudge me in the right direction? I'm digging through the docs and while some people say use globals, others say avoid them. Some people swear by query vars and others say to never use them.

What is the best practice for sending data to a page?